# List the names of any customers who have used all payment methods

Tags: mysql, sql

[image: Customer]

[image: Payment Method]

payment option , c, e, m.
How can i find who use all payment method and show their names

I tried

```
 SELECT cr.id, cr.firstName, cr.lastName FROM customer cr
 INNER JOIN purchase pm
 ON (cr.id = paymentmethod.customer)
 WHERE pm.paymethod="c" and pm.paymethod="e" and pm.paymethod="m"
 ORDER BY cr.name DESC
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another approach could be

```
SELECT c.* FROM customer c
INNER JOIN 
(SELECT DSITINCT pm1.customer from purchase pm1
  INNER JOIN purchase pm2 on pm1.customer = pm2.customer and pm2.paymethod = 'e'
  INNER JOIN purchase pm3 on pm1.customer = pm3.customer and pm3.paymethod = 'm' 
  WHERE pm1.paymethod = 'c') ids
ON c.id = ids.customer
```

I think the paymentmethod to pick for pm1 should be the least favourite one...

Answer (score 3):

You can use aggregation and counting:

```
SELECT cr.id, cr.firstName, cr.lastName
FROM customer cr INNER JOIN
     purchase pm
     ON cr.id = pm.customer
WHERE pm.paymethod IN ('c', 'e', 'm')
GROUP BY cr.id, cr.firstName, cr.lastName
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT pm.paymethod) = 3    -- number of methods in list
ORDER BY cr.name DESC;
```

There are other approaches as well.  If you are looking for three specific payment methods, you can use `EXISTS` as well:

```
select c.*
from customer c
where exists (select 1
              from purchase pm
              where cr.id = pm.customer and pm.paymethod = 'c'
             ) and
      exists (select 1
              from purchase pm
              where cr.id = pm.customer and pm.paymethod = 'e'
             ) and
      exists (select 1
              from purchase pm
              where cr.id = pm.customer and pm.paymethod = 'm'
             );
```

Because this avoids the `group by` in the outer query, it is likely to be much faster than the first query (assuming you have an index on `(customer, paymentmethod)`.

Comment: @KayesFahim . . . Is the only reason that the table name was wrong?  I fixed the answer.